# Android studio - Task 'assemble' not found in project ':google-play-services_lib'

Tags: android, gradle, maps

When I click `Build -> Rebuild Project` I get this error.

[image]

Everyrithing is fine with the map. I successfully sync build.gradle and clean project without errors. And I can run on my device the map.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'

}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion '20'

  defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 10
      targetSdkVersion 20
    }   
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: You must have some `google-play-services_lib` in your settings.gradle file. What's that about?

Comment: Yes. I have it. settings.gradle - `include ':MyProject', ':google-play-services_lib'
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a reference to `google-play-services_lib` in your **settings.gradle** file. Unless you have a module in a directory called "google-play-services_lib" off of your project root, which I assume you don't, then remove this bit from your settings file. The correct way to add a dependency on Play Services is not by adding this to your settings file, but by a `compile` statement in your `dependencies` block of your **build.gradle** file, as you have already done:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

Comment: lol. You was right. I had an old project and forgot to delete it :D Thanks for the help :)